# Breaking down and grouping data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not the best with MYSQL queries but this one has got me stumped on the best way to do this, my basic sample MYSQL data is:

```
INSERT INTO `spending` (`spend_id`, `spend_user_id`, `spend_sender_id`, `spend_offer_id`, `spend_amount`, `spend_click`, `spend_date`) VALUES
(2, 190, 190, 34591, '0.15', 1, '2018-05-14 22:39:47'),
(3, 190, 190, 34591, '0.15', 1, '2018-05-14 22:39:52'),
(4, 190, 7, 34591, '0.15', 1, '2018-05-14 22:40:07'),
(5, 190, 10, 34591, '0.15', 1, '2018-05-14 22:42:15'),
(6, 190, 7, 34591, '0.15', 1, '2018-05-15 06:55:56'),
(7, 190, 7, 34591, '0.15', 1, '2018-05-16 17:05:29'),
(8, 190, 7, 34591, '0.15', 1, '2018-05-16 17:05:32');
```

My objective is to break down the data into 2 main sections **Clicks** and **Cost** essentially every entry is regarded as 1 click, the html dashboard is like: 
[image]

then 4 sub sections.

The 4 sub sections is clicks and cost for **today, yesterday, last week, last month** for `spend_user_id` i don't know the best way to do this, any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you made any attempt at doing this yourself?

Comment: Very badly i'm afraid, i can show lots of wrong code and queries that do not work! i have spent a crazy amount of time on it so far.

Comment: Show the one that you think is closest, if nothing else it gives us an insite innto what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need separate subqueries for each column of your displays (today, yesterday, week, month).

For example to get the month-to-date results, use this subquery.

```
        SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
          FROM spending
         WHERE spend_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Once you have all those subqueries, you can join them together to get your results. (Note well: each subquery yields just one row, so joining them without
`ON` conditions also yields one row.)

Something like this. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8e090/7/0)

```
SELECT today.clicks, today.spend_amount, 
       yesterday.clicks, yesterday.spend_amount,
       week.clicks, week.spend_amount,
       month.clicks, month.spend_amount
  FROM
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= CURDATE()) today
   JOIN           
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
               AND spend_date < CURDATE()) yesterday
   JOIN
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
               AND spend_date < CURDATE()) week
   JOIN        
           (SELECT COUNT(*) clicks, SUM(spend_amount) spend_amount
              FROM spending
             WHERE spend_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) month
```

I'm guessing what you mean, exactly, by today, yesterday, week, and month. You need to figure that out before your report will make business sense.

Comment: Just want to add before OP says this is not the desired output, as this  answer is exactly what I would do. If you need to compare your date for current week with either sunday or monday you can use `DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(current_date)) DAY)` to get the last sunday, change `1-DAYOFWEEK` for `2-DAYOFWEEK` to get monday. You can also use `DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')` to get the first of the current month.

Comment: this is indeed the desired results, thank you very much, i was way off in my testing.